# Compute the next element fast.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, recurrence-relations

If I know what the value of  $x^{n^2}$ how can I compute $x^{(n+1)^2}$ using the recurrence relation?

It would be nice if the method was as fast as possible.

I need this in order to compute $x^{1^2} + x^{2^2} + ... + x^{n^2}$ as fast as I can.

Comment: I am sorry, my comments were wrong... You still need an iterated solution

Comment: That only works if it is a product of $x^{n^2}$. In your case where you sum up the $x^{n^2}$s there should not be any closed form simplifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n+1$, which gives
$$
x^{(n+1)^2} = x^{n^2}\cdot x^{2n+1}
$$
and remember that $x^{2n+1} = x^{2(n-1) + 1}\cdot x^2$. So the loop looks something like this:

1. receive two variables from the previous iteration: $x^{n^2}$ itself, and $x^{2n-1}$
2. multiply $x^{2n-1}$ with $x^2$ to make $x^{2n+1}$
3. multiply $x^{n^2}$ with $x^{2n+1}$ to make $x^{(n+1)^2}$
4. use $x^{(n+1)^2}$, whether that's adding to a summation variable or printing or whatever
5. send $x^{(n+1)^2}$ and $x^{2n+1}$ on to the next iteration

Comment: Seems pretty fast for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the recurrence relation of the given sequence, we have $$x^{(n)^2(n+1)^2}=(a_n )^{(n+1)^2}=(a_{n+1})^{n^2}$$

$$\implies (a_{n+1})^{n^2}=(a_n )^{(n+1)^2} \implies a_{n+1}=a_n^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}}$$

Hence,

$$a_{n+1}=a_n^{1+1/n +1/n^2}$$

Comment: Why does the equality holds? Could you, please, provide the inference steps?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it if would be the fastest procedure, but for instance, since to compute $x^{n^2}$, you need to have calculated $x^n$, you may save this value in a variable, and compute $x^{(n+1)^2}$ as
$$\bigl(x^n\bigr)^n\cdot\bigl(x^n\bigr)^2\cdot x $$