# Compute the sum fast.

Tags: summation, algorithms

How can I compute the following sum in the fastest way possible?

$y = 1 + x + ... + {x}^{{n}^{3}}=\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{x}^{{i}^{3}}$

I wrote that $n^3 - (n-1)^3 = 3n^2-3n+1$, but so far it does not help a lot.

Comment: @Joppy, I updated the question.

Comment: Why do you believe it has a closed form?

Comment: @Galc127, I hope for a good recurrence relation between addendums at least.

Comment: [My answer to your previous, very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541156/compute-the-next-element-fast/2541171#2541171) should adapt quite well, I think. There is a little more to keep track of, but that should be it. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Arthur, yes, but it did not help.

Comment: Without quantifying what you mean by "fastest way" and what memory constraints there are, there is no effective way to answer your question. So, what do you mean by "fast" and what are the memory constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a modified version of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541156/compute-the-next-element-fast/2541171#2541171), which was the same question only with square exponents rather than cubed ones.

You have already calculated $x^{(n+1)^3} = x^{n^3}\cdot x^{3(n+1)^2-3(n+1)+1}$ (I shifted the indices by one to conform with my other answer). We also have $x^{3(n+1)^2-3(n+1)+1}=x^{3n^2-3n+1}\cdot x^{6n}$. You could then use the following recursion:

1. Get $x^{n^3}, x^{3n^2 - 3n +1}$ and $x^{6n-6}$ from previous iteration
2. Calculate $x^{6n} = x^{6n-6}\cdot x^6$
3. Calculate $x^{3(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) + 1} = x^{3n^2 - 3n +1}\cdot x^{6n}$
4. Calculate $x^{(n+1)^3} = x^{n^3}\cdot x^{3(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) + 1}$
5. Add $x^{(n+1)^3}$ to your summation variable
6. Send $x^{(n+1)^3}, x^{3(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) + 1}$ and $x^{6n}$ to the next iteration

Comment: The only problem which I can not put up with is that now I have to store a lot of data from previous steps.

Comment: Storing three numbers usually isn't that much, are you certain that that's a problem? Also, there will always be a tradeoff between memory and time. You could store no numbers between iterations if you just calculated each term from scratch, but you don't want to do that, because if you did you wouldn't come here asking for advice. I believe that this is a good tradeoff, as I don't think it's possible to do much faster, and I'm not using a lot of storage, given how abundant memory is these days in hardware and software.

Comment: Could you, please, comment what is wrong here? If I substitute n = 1 in $x^{3(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) + 1} = x^{3n^2 - 3n +1}\cdot x^{6n+6}$ I won`t get an equality.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww You're right, I found a sign mistake in my notes. That ought to be correct now.

Comment: I got $x^{3(n+1)^2-3(n+1)+1}=x^{3n^2+3n+1}$ instead of $x^{3(n+1)^2-3(n+1)+1}=x^{3n^2-3n+1}\cdot x^{6n}$... Am I right?

Comment: Note that $x^{3n^2+3n+1} = x^{3n^2-3n+1}\cdot x^{6n}$. So, yes, they are the same. It's just that expressed as $x^{3n^2-3n+1}\cdot x^{6n}$ it is easier to relate directly to the calculations from the previous iteration.